# Need help for Upgrade script in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello I am new on magneto-1.x and I want to create upgrade script to add column also while alter table I want to check whether column exists or not in the table.
I have tried this but not working:

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->run("ALTER TABLE {$this-getTable('lr_extended_profile_data')} ADD COLUMN `total_logins`  INT(11) NULL;");
$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$installer = $this;
```

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('email_leave_review')}`
    ADD COLUMN `used` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER `status`,
");

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my question is:
i have created i install file and in that i have created a table like:
$this->run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('lr_extended_profile_data')} (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `total_logins` int(11) NOT NULL );");
Also i have created a upgrade file for already existing customer who are using the plugin, i had written this
$this->startSetup();
$this->run("ALTER TABLE {$this-getTable('lr_extended_profile_data')} ADD COLUMN `total_logins`  INT(11) NULL;");
$this->endSetup();

Comment: So problem i am facing is that if customer upgrade the plugin then it is working fine but if someone tries to install fresh plugin then it is showing error like column already exists

Comment: Also can you tell me how to compare module version in upgrade script

Comment: mysql4-upgrade-1.1.1-1.1.2.php   In this 1.1.1 is old version and 1.1.2 is new version and please update new version in config.xml also.

Comment: i have upgraded the version in config.xml file but still i am getting the problem like:
if customer upgrade the plugin then it is working fine but if someone tries to install fresh plugin then it is showing error like column already exists